# Magical Record add object, different context error

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm using Magical Record in my app, and want to add the functionality for a user to add a 'Note', which is a child of 'entry'.

I added this code:

```
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock: ^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        Note *newNote = [Note MR_createInContext: localContext];

        newNote.content = noteContent;
        newNote.name = @"User Note";

        [self.entry addNotesObject: newNote];
     }
                      completion: ^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                          if (error != nil)
                          {
                              // show alert
                          }
                          else if (success)
                          {
                              [[self tableView] reloadData];
                          }
                      }];
```

The error I keep getting on the last line is "Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'entry' between objects in different contexts"

I tried setting the context of both 'entry' and 'newNote' to 'localContext', but I still get the same error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`self.entry` was created in different context, so you can't access it from this one.
Instead of:

```
[self.entry addNotesObject: newNote];
```

you should first find `self.entry` object in `localContext`:

```
[[self.entry MR_inContext:localContext] addNotesObject: newNote];
```

You can find an explanation of using MagicalRecord in a concurrent environment at [Performing Core Data operations on Threads](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/develop/Docs/Threads.md). Though it's quite short, so in my opinion it's worthwhile to read [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001200-SW1) even though you don't use CD directly.