# MagicalRecord saveWithBlock: no error, no success

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

While importing data using `[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:]` processed by `NSXMLParser`, I occasionally get a situation where the error is nil, and success is NO:

```
- (void) importData:(NSData *) data
{
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock: ^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        Root *rootObject = [[Root alloc] init];
        rootObject.context = localContext;

        NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: data];

        parser.delegate = rootObject;
        [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces: YES];
        [parser parse]
    }
                  completion: ^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                      if (error)
                      {
                         // show alert
                      }
                      else if (success)
                      {
                         // update UI
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          NSLog(@"no error, no success");
                      } 
    }];
```

This has come up before ([Magical Record add object, different context error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165704/magical-record-add-object-different-context-error)), and there I fixed it by using localContext to create the entities when parsing the data. I'm doing that now as well, but the issue has returned, so maybe something else is going on?

The data is obtained using the `AFNetworking` framework, and `importData:` is called from within the completionBlock of an `AFHTTPSessionManager` GET call.

If I put a breakpoint at the `NSLog` call, I see that a lot of threads are open, maybe that's a clue?

EDIT: I have checked that the parser does not return an error.

UPDATE:
This is the code for the root element, and it progresses like this through the whole xml file. Once it finds an 'entry', it will parse that, and add nodes, etc, etc. This design pattern is based on the RSS example project in the BNR iOS book.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:      (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{   
     if ([elementName isEqualToString: @"entry"])
     {
         Entry *e = [Entry MR_createInContext: self.context];
//        Entry *e = [Entry MR_createEntity];

         NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
         [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

         e.dateModified = [dateFormatter dateFromString: attributeDict[@"modified"]];
         e.version = attributeDict[@"version"];

         [e setContext: self.context];
         [e setParentParserDelegate: self];
         [parser setDelegate: e];

         if (!self.entries)
             self.entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

         [self.entries addObject: e];
     }
 }
```

This code works flawlessly when adding one (1) record.  If I import several at once, I occasionally get a 'no success, no error' situation.

EDIT2:  This is the code that calls the importData method:

```
[myAFNetworkingClient searchForQuery: queryString
               withParameters: nil
                   completion: ^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                       if (data && data.length) {
                           [self importData: data];
                       } else {
                           if ([error code] != NSURLErrorCancelled)
                           {
                               [error showAlert];
                           }
                       }
                   }];
```

EDIT3: Ok, I *may* have a hunch what is going on. The only time I get this situation (error is nil, and success is NO), is when I call `myAFNetworkingClient searchForQuery` many times in a for-loop (to update  a bunch of entries with new ones from the database), and for every call a different localContext is/may be used, right?. So, when the xml is parsed, and Entities are created, this happens with different contexts. Now, what if two xml files both contain an element (let's say a person) that is the same for two entries? If one parser already has created an `Entity` for `Person`, and then the second parser also needs to do that amoment later, will that cause a conflict, because `Person` already exists? Am I on the right track here? And if so, is there a way around this?

Comment: Hi Koen — it's a bit hard to tell without more detail — would you mind updating the question to include everything inside your save block? As it stands, nothing in the save block you've posted above inserts, modifies or deletes a managed object that I can see.

Comment: Just a quick comment before I add the code a bit later.  My xml file is big, and not one-on-one, so I am manually going through each node, and based on the value and attributes, I create new entities, and insert those. Unfortunately, because of this complex structure of the xml, I cannot use the 'super easy fetching' that MR supports.

Comment: Is it possible that there's nothing to be saved?  I have a vague recollection of being told that if there's nothing to save, `saveWithBlock:` calls the block with `success` value `NO` but `error` value `nil`.

Comment: MagicalRecord _should_ pass back yes to the competion block if there are no changes to the context, so that's not the problem here. I'd imagine there are probably a few spots where you're performing operations on objects in other contexts. We'll see when the rest of the code is posted, I guess :)

Comment: The line `[e setContext: self.context];` — why are you setting this?

Comment: Why are you setting the parser delegate to the last created entity? Also, don't change the context on a managed object after you create it. There lies dragons.

Comment: @Tony: I'm setting the context (a property of all my entities), so I can call `Entry *e = [Entry MR_createInContext: self.context];`  I think I made this change (from `Entry *e = [Entry MR_createEntity];`), because of the problem I had in the other issue (see link in above).  Would the latter actually be the way to go?   @casademora: I'm passing on the parser delegate so each class/entity can process the xml data as needed - this is based on the example in the BNR book.

Comment: I've added more code above to show how `saveWithBlock` is called.

Comment: See my third edit above for a possible cause.

Comment: @Koen, it's unnecessary — every NSManagedObject instance/subclass instance has a method `managedObjectContext` that does exactly what your custom `context` property does. Get rid of it and use the supplied version ;)

Comment: @Koen, your assumption in Update 3 is correct — if any of the network requests overlap, there's no guarantee that your objects will do any kind of reproducible de-duplication. I don't know that this is causing your error, but you could try executing your networking requests (or at least your data import requests) on a serial queue.

Comment: I've added a dispatch_sync for each import in the for-loop, but I still see an occasional 'no error, no success' being logged. So something else must still be going on. I also ditched the context property as recommended above. I'll keep digging.

Comment: Ok, I think I found it. I was completely removing and re-importing data into entities. Initially, I was doing the delete and import in the same emumeration block, and I got the occasional error. I now moved them to two emumeration blocks, separated by `[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];`, and the problem seems to be gone.

Comment: Dangit, still getting these occasionally, I'm stumped... So, regardless of my code, in which situations will `saveWithBlock:` return "no error, no success' ?

Comment: @Koen: Have you found out why?

Comment: @el.severo: Sorry, I honestly don't remember. I am also no longer using MagicalRecord, so it is going to be difficult to go back in my code and see what could have been the cause.